# How to plot a subset of data in R using a ggplot tool

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new in using R
I would like to plot specific variables which are in one main column nominated "Variable".

`ID Sex Variables Value Condition ValueMin`

```
library ("ggplot")
EF<-ggplot(antdata, aes (variable$EF1, variable$EF6.1, variables$EF6.2, EF11.1, EF 11.2, ValueMIN, fill = ConditionCode)
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `EF11.1, EF 11.2`? What is `ID Sex Variables Value Condition ValueMin`?

Comment: Why is there a space here:  `aes (` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*this does not work*"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: "variable" != "variables" or for that matter "Variable". "Condition" != "ConditionCode". Put more effort into checking your question for accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the visualization you are attempting to create, but here is what I would do:

1. Create a new `data.frame` that filters the variables you want to plot. I would use the filter function from the `dplyr` package -- i.e. `filter(df,variable=="EF1")` -- to do this, though there are of course many ways.
2. You can then use `ggplot` to render the new `data.frame` you have created. Remember that you need to specify `x` and `y` values in `ggplot`, and anything else you want to specify needs to be done via the `fill` and `shape` specifications. So often you need to reshape your data to have it fit. The `melt` function from the `reshape2` package is one I've found very useful when doing work with `ggplot` (though I think you can get by with just the filter function for your specific example provided here).

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for posting an answer. As a tip, use the back quote to include code in text.

Comment: Sorry if the post was confusing. Here more details.

Comment: ID ConditionCode Sex Horn EF ValueEF EB ValueEB
1 1 1 2 1 EFBaseline 18.96 EBBaseline 6
2 2 1 2 2 EFBaseline 33.6 EBBaseline 8.53

Comment: this is my data base a small portion called antdata.  I would like to plot (bar or boxplot) ValueEf across EF taking into account ConditionCode (5 level).

library(ggplot2)
EF<-ggplot(antdata, aes(antdata$EF, antdata$ValueEF, fill = CnditionCode))